# how to update from textbox to database with oledb VFP in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, visual-foxpro, dbf

Dear All Programmmer,

if I use the manual the database immediately updates but if I use the textbox the database does not update but only an update messagebox appears. Is there something wrong with the code or any other best recommendations?. I'm using visual studio 2015

Thanks

```
           Dim pathDBF As String = Application.StartupPath()
        Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Concat("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" & pathDBF))
                 Dim tableDBF = "RSD, GSD, GPD, FFG, RPD"
            cn.Open()
            For Each tableName In tableDBF.Split(","c)
                   Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format("update {0} set Item=? where Item==?", tableDBF.Trim()), cn)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("Item", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Item", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
                MessageBox.Show("updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Next
                cn.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: What value does `ExecuteNonQuery` return?

Comment: I've never used FoxPro but I would assume that, if the commented line is inserting literal text values then so is the second. Wrapping the `?` symbols in double-quotes would be indicating that they are literal text. If you want them to be interpreted as parameters then you would presumably need just a `?` symbol on its own, i.e. `"update {0} set Itemproduct=? where Itemproduct=?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use parameters (?), you wouldn't use any quotes around them and also be sure you specify them in the order they appear in your SQL string (you did correct):

```
Dim pathDBF As String = Application.StartupPath()
            Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source={pathDBF}")
                Dim tableDBF = "RSD, GSD, GPD, FFG, RPD"
                cn.Open()
                For Each table In tableDBF.Split(","c)
                    'Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format("update {0} set Itemproduct=""Drink 1015 Full"" where Itemproduct==""Drink 1015""", tableDBF.Trim()), cn)
                    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format("update {0} set Itemproduct=? where Itemproduct==?", table.Trim()), cn)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("Itemproduct1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text 'Drink 1015 Full
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("Itemproduct2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text 'Drink 1015
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                    MessageBox.Show("updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Next
                cn.Close()
            End Using
```

EDIT: You can also make it more readable writing like this:

```
Dim sql As String = <sql>update {0} 
    set Itemproduct=? 
    where Itemproduct==?
    </sql>
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format(sql, tableDBF.Trim()), cn)
'...
```

EDIT: Use this code as is:

```
Dim pathDBF As String = Application.StartupPath()
Dim sql As String = <sql>
update {0} 
set Itemproduct=? 
where Itemproduct==?
</sql>
Dim tableDBF = "RSD, GSD, GPD, FFG, RPD"

Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source={0}",pathDBF))
    cn.Open()
    For Each table In tableDBF.Split(","c)
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format(sql, table.Trim()), cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Itemproduct1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Itemproduct2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Next
    cn.Close()
End Using
MessageBox.Show("updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply from you and sorry I replied late.  I have an error in the line code `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` `Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword.`

Comment: @roy, with the latter? Use the former one than (a single line). Also I noticed your parameter names are same, make them different. ie: ip1, ip2

Comment: ` Use the former one than (a single line).` you mean this in the textbox. `cmd.Parameters.Add("IP1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text` 
`cmd.Parameters.Add("IP2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text`

Comment: @roy, no I meant string.Format("update {0} ... instead of dim sql as string.

Comment: still the same error. `Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format("update {0} set Itemproduct=""Drink 1015 Full"" where Itemproduct==""Drink 1015""", tableDBF.Trim()), cn)` if I use this code without textbox it works and without errors

Comment: @roy, no that is not what I suggested. Please copy paste from the code I put in there above.

Comment: @roy, I later noticed how you erroneously used tableDbf.Trim() instead of table.Trim(). Editing.

Comment: `Dim pathDBF As String = Application.StartupPath()
        Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Concat("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" & pathDBF))
            Dim tableDBF = "RSD, GSD, GPD, FFG, RPD"
            cn.Open()
            For Each tableName In tableDBF.Split(","c)
                Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format("update {0} set Item=? where Item==?", tableDBF.Trim()), cn)`

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("Item", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Item", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
                MessageBox.Show("updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Next
                cn.Close()
        End Using` Field name "itemproduct" change to "item"

Comment: @roy, I don't understand what you mean. Editing again and putting all the code that you need to use.

Comment: `I later noticed how you erroneously used tableDbf.Trim() instead of table.Trim(). Editing.` I've changed to `tableDBF.Trim()` but Still still error you can see the code I pasted

Comment: @roy, no I put the code that you need to use. Copy & paste and use that one as is.

Comment: the last code of yours went perfectly. Can you explain why the previous code had the error?

Comment: @roy, as I said, I didn't notice before that you used tableDbf.Trim(). Otherwise, just making it table.Trim() would work from the start. In one case you are trimming and using "RSD, GSD, GPD, FFG, RPD" and in the other individual table names like "RSD".

Comment: you're right the previous code also worked after I changed from "tableDBF" to "table" . thanks for the answer